# URL with special characters not opening

Tags: c#, asp.net

Uri with `+` symbol is not opening.. 
for example I have a file in folder !+123@1, want to show it in browser.   `window.open(url);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `encodeURIComponent`

```
window.open("http://your-url.com/" + encodeURIComponent("foo+123.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The web browser interprets the plus `+` symbol as space. Use encodeURIComponent to encode it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how the text translates by using encodeURIComponent or online tool
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

`+` translates to `%2B`